# How to use ffmpeg merge all the videos in the catalog in an orderly manner?

Tags: bash, shell, video, ffmpeg, iterm

I have a lot of regular video clips
1.mp4
2.mp4
...
11.mp4

I use command below to combine all the clips: 
`ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i <(for f in ./*.mp4; do echo "file '$PWD/$f'"; done) -c copy -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 30 all.mp4`

But the sequence will be disordered， For example, the file #1 is not file #2, but file #11。

how can I correctly merge according to the number size sequence?

Comment: Rename files with zero-padding (`001.mp4`, `002.mp4`, `003.mp4`, etc), or add `sort -V` / `sort --version-sort` for "natural" or "version" sorting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add sort -V as below:

`ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i <(for f in ./*.webm; do echo "file '$PWD/$f'"; done | sort -V) -c copy -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 30 output.webm`